# how to enable check box single checked when i click on item of list view item

Tags: java, android

```
public class SingleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    List<String> data;

    public SingleListAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        ctx = context;
        this.data = data;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_items, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleitemId)).setText(data.get(position));


        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my adapter class :

```
String[] data = {"10-11 Am", "11-12Am", "12-2Pm", "2-4PM", "4-6Pm"};


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list.add(data[i]);
        }

        SingleListAdapter     adapter = new SingleListAdapter(this, list);


        listview.setAdapter(adapter);



        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                valueoflist=   data[i];            



            }
        });
```

this is my lsitview itemclick function i have  textview and checkbox in listview adapter i am printing value in a textview   and i am able to get data of Particular item on listview item click i want when i click on item list then that particular check box should enable please suggest me how we can do this like and i want single choice checked item click please help me suggest me how we can do this .

Comment: Did you solve it? can you explain your solution?

Answer (score 0):

In onItemClick method you can call your checkBox object and you can work with it.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            valueoflist=   data[i];            
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.your_check_box_id);
            chk.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
```

I hope it will help you

Try this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnMyItemClickListener());
```

and declare:

```
private class OnMyItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
            valueoflist=   data[i];            
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.your_check_box_id);
            chk.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

But.. a question.. can you show the listview initialize?

Comment: BUt i want only Single check Box not all check box selected i mean if i  click item 2then it should  enable  2item check box now if we click on third then previous item should be disapper and 3r should be checked

Comment: if you use findViewById referenced to a specified view you are selecting the view object with this id in specified view. In fact you should use view.findViewById cause view is a parameter of onItemClick, so you are finding view object with this id in view passed by onItemClick.

Comment: so what we should apply for this can u please tell me

Comment: It's the code I shared before. CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.your_check_box_id);

Comment: but what happen in your given code  that all check box checked but i want when ever i item clcik list only that postion should check not previous checkdenabled

Comment: Try to use     view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_items, null); instead of      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_items, parent, false);

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/BWRk4MiWdKhmFr7fMdcK4s  look this code please @ZanoOnStack

Comment: try to log the name of view getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()), it should be single_choice_items